# How to connect a Raspberry Pi 4B to an Apple Studio Display?

Tags: hdmi, display, macos

I have a Raspberry Pi 4B and I'd like to use my Apple Studio Display as a monitor for it.

How can I do this? Would a cable or adapter work to go from the Raspberry Pi HDMI output to the Studio Display Thunderbolt input? Could anyone recommend any hardware that would allow me to do this please if this is the right approach?

The available connections for the display can be found here:
https://www.apple.com/uk/studio-display/specs/

Also, it'd be great if there was some way I could switch between my Mac Studio (which is usually connected to the display) and the Raspberry Pi connection to it.

Any thoughts would be appreciated!!